# AFNetworking, callback when finished request?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsarray, afnetworking

I wonder if it's possible to get a callback when `AFNetworking`finished a request? I'm making an app in which I have a edge case, all downloaded items is checked `is_deleted` (and should not be displayed in the UI). If this is case I would like to automatically try to download older data (create a new `AFNetworking` request).

I have tried to call my `loadData` method again, from itself. But it creates an infinitive loop. Like this:

```
- (void)loadDataIsOlder:(NSNumber *)older
{    
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.streamUrl];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
    operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {
        NSDictionary *data = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSDictionary *meta = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"meta"];
       [...]
        for (NSNumber *deleted in (NSArray *)[data valueForKey:@"is_deleted"]) {
            if ([deleted boolValue] == YES) {
                self.shouldTryToLoadMore = YES;
            } else {
                self.shouldTryToLoadMore = NO;
            }
        }
        if (self.shouldTryToLoadMore == YES) {
            [self loadDataIsOlder:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        }
    } [...]
}
```

So, I wonder if it's some other / better way to do what I want.

**Subquestion** 
The array `(NSArray *)[data valueForKey:@"is_deleted"]` consists of BOOL int values. I wonder if its possible to easily calculate the values of an array containing ints, e.g. [1, 1, 1, 0] = 3? I want to check if all values in the array is 1:s.

Answer (score 1):

**I am not familiar with AFNetworking**

> > I wonder if it's possible to get a callback when AFNetworking finished a request?

You could always set the completion block of the operation (will be called even on failure, on the thread the operation run in so be careful with UI updates).
like so: `operation.completionBlock = ^{/*what ever you like to accomplish*/};`

> > all downloaded items is checked is_deleted

I'm spotting a little problem in your algorithm.
You are not accumulating the deletion keys properly (you only respond to the last item status).
try: `self.shouldTryToLoadMore &= [deleted boolValue];` instead of your `if` statement.

If you like something shorted (to avoid the "visible" loop) try:

```
NSMutableSet* set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:[data valueForKey:@"is_deleted"]];
[set addObject:@YES];
if ([set count] == 1) {
//You have only deleted items in your request
}
```

**note**
You are capturing `self` in the success block, which might be problematic (retain cycle if you own the operation in `self`).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a retry counter and put it in the failure block, so it would look something like this:

```
        - (void)loadDataIsOlder:(NSNumber *)older
    {   
 if (shouldTrytoReloadMore){
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.streamUrl];
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
        operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {
            NSDictionary *data = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"];
            NSDictionary *meta = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"meta"];
           [...]
            for (NSNumber *deleted in (NSArray *)[data valueForKey:@"is_deleted"]) {
                if ([deleted boolValue] == YES) {
                    self.shouldTryToLoadMore = YES;
                    [self loadDataIsOlder:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

                } else {
                    self.shouldTryToLoadMore = NO;
                }
            }
            }
        } [...]
    }
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
}
```

WHen you call the method the first time, set n as the number of times you need to retry.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if I nedd to retry, before I get the data. Could this solution work anyway?

Comment: Sorry misread the question.  You can add up, all the BOOL's in the array and compare with the total number in the array, which will tell if all the values in the array are 1

Comment: I think you read the question correctly first. But I only know if I need to retry the method, when I'm in the method (or get the data), not before.